# Trying to draw SVG to canvas, but it's being cut short

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, drawing

http://jsfiddle.net/NV6Cr/1/

If you click "Create Canvas", it'll draw the SVG text at the bottom of the page onto the canvas.  The only problem is that it's only taking the top left portion of the text.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried hosting the svg as a separate file and setting the image src to the path of that file?

Comment: I moved it over to a separate SVG file and set it as the image's source before drawing the image, and I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the SVG so its size matches the canvas and it works on Firefox for me e.g.

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" class="layer" id="layer_text" width="778" height="544">`

Comment: Gotta be kidding me; it was that easy?  Thank you!